# Changing input field based on other input

Tags: jquery, html

Hello and thanks for the help ahead of time. Note that I am new to this, which will probably explain why I can't figure out the issue.

I am trying to dynamically change the value of an input text field when the value of a dropdown is changed.

head of my page:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="projectJS.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // initialize the value of the input field to the selected value
            // of the dropdown list:
            $("#membfee").val($("#role").val());

            $("#role").click(function() {
               // when the value of the dropdown list changes
               // update the input field
               $("#membfee").val("111");
             });
        });​
    </script>        
</head>
```

I don't thing there are any issues with the jquery, it's all pretty simple.  Are you able to reference an external javascript file and jquery like I did above?

Section of the body containing the dropdown menu and text field I wish to update:

```
<tr>
    <td class="label_block">Membership Term:</td>
    <td>    <select name="role" id="role" />
                <option value="Trial">Trial</option>
                <option value="1 Month">1 Month</option>
                <option value="3 Month">3 Month</option>
                <option value="6 Month">6 Month</option>
                <option value="Year">Year</option>
            </select>   
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class ="label_block">Membership Fee:</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="15" name="membfee" id="membfee" value="" /></td>
    <td class="error">
        <%out.print(membfee_msg);%>  
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/):

```
$("#role").change(function() {
    // when the value of the dropdown list changes
    // update the input field
    $("#membfee").val("111");
});
```

Are you sure there aren't any JS errors on the page, because it [just should work](http://jsfiddle.net/xk8KL/).

Comment: sorry, i actually had it as .change() function and just had the click method in just to try it.

Comment: It should work. Perhaps you have an error on the page? And what is ProtectJS? Maybe it conflicts with jQuery.

Comment: projectjs.js just has a couple functions, I was worried that maybe I can't reference both, but when I comment out the line linking to the javascript file the issue persists.  This is a JSP file incase that might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `change()` event instead:

```
$("#role").change(function(){
    // blabla
})
```